# java.lang.instrument vs JVM TI

Tags: java, profiling

I plan on writing some profiling software on top of our current Java code and found JVM TI and java.lang.instrument.
I was looking for something that would not impact the performance of the original code and would also allow profiling of:

1. The time taken by functions
2. The memory used by specific variables throughout a function call

Anyhow, what are the differences between JVM TI and java.lang.instrument? I do know that JVM TI uses C/C++ code and is platform-dependent, while java.lang.instrument is just a Java API, so this really makes java.lang.instrument more attractive. However, what benefits does JVM TI have over java.lang.instrument, if any?

Comment: Do existing Java profiling packages not do what you want?